# Edit init file in order to remap ctrl to enter via xcape

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, init

I'm trying to remap cnrl to the caps lock and enter keys in way similar to the program karabiner for macOS. I found the following site

http://emacsredux.com/blog/2016/01/30/remap-return-to-control-in-gnu-slash-linux/

which suggests using Xcape by putting some text into the login shell's init file. Assume this is the best way to go about this is Solus, can anyone point me in the right direction so that I might figure out how to access the init file and accomplish this remapping?
I'm pretty new to Linux, so please keep that in mind. If I need to read up on some area, please do let me know.

Update: I've created a file named .bash_profile with the appropriate commands have have sourced it with . .bash_profile. It works! Remaining issue: it seems that I need to execute this command each time I login. Is there a way to make this file read at startup?